# Updating object in firebase using angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using angular firebase application , a client has updated the purchase request of some commodity , using the below method in firebase ...

```
 addPurchaseRequest(data, uid: string) {

 this.db.database.ref("/purchaserequests/").push(data);

 }
```

I got the below 2 purchases in firebase

```
purchaserequests
  -LXZVHEpbxfpJzt_el10
      actualbonus: 12312,
      uid:1,
      status:,
      approvedon:''
  -LXFSADSpbxfpJzt_el11
      actualbonus: 12,
      uid:2,
      status:0,
      approvedon:''
```

now i want to update the status and date for uid = 1

```
 updatepurchaserequest(rid : string , amount : number , reason: string) {
  const dataObj = {
  status: 1
    approvedon: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
   };
  this.db.database.ref("/purchaserequests/").set(dataObj);
```

But this is not working and replacing the complete purchase request object.

I need something like where clause of Mysql , which says update dataObj where uid =1

Comment: Firebase doesn't have the concept of update queries. You will have to execute the query (`orderByChild("uid").equalTo(1)`), and then loop over the results and call update on each matching node individually.

Comment: thanks , can i put 2 where clause ..like update where uid = 1 and where approvedon = ' ' ? thanks in advance

Comment: Firebase queries can only contain one condition. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 0):

I think that you probably must be edit by $key or make your uid like your $key

When you get your data, you could do this:

```
yourData.forEach( u => {
  const _data = u.payload.toJSON();
  _data['$key'] = u.key;
  this.inactiveUsers.unshift(_data);
})
```

With this, the $key is part of your data and if you want to update it, you could do this:

```
this.db.database.ref(purchaserequests).child($key).update(item);
```

And, if you want to update one or more parameters:

```
this.db.database.ref(`purchaserequests/${$key}`).update({ [atribute]: value });
```

Comment: thanks , but the key need to be unique as one uid can  add many purchaserequests

Comment: ok! but the key I said, is the key that firebase puts, so it will be unique. by the other hand, yuo could put your uid like a $key of your object. By
`this.db.database.ref(`purchaserequests/{yourUID}`).set(item);`